# Want to be able to receive an empty string instead of null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc model with a string property, when i receive json parameter with is set on client to empty string i receive null i mvc controller action for the string parameter.

I want to be able to receive an empty string instead of null and have tried the following:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TestClassMetaData))]
public partial class TestClass
{
}

public class TestClassMetaData
{
     private string _note;

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max 50 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public object Note
    {
        get { return _note; }
        set { _note = (string)value ?? ""; }
    }

}
```

Using this is generating validation error.

Does anybody know why it's not working?

And also why is the metadata class using object for property type?

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
```

to the property definition of `Note` (which should really be of type `string`).

Answer (score 1):

By default `DefaultModelBinder` uses default value of `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` which is `true`.

I you want to change this behaviour you should use `DisplayFormat` attribute and set property `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` to `false` for string properties.

```
public class YourModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

I have not checked fillowing solution but you can try it and implement your custom model binder for all string properties in your project.

```
public class CustomStringBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Having implemented custom string binder you should register it in Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new StringBinder());
    }
}
```

I hope this code works.